# Django Rest Framework - Updating a foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am a bit frustrated with this problem using the Django Rest Framework:

I am using a **viewset**, with a `custom serializer`. This serializer has its `depth set to 1`. When i query this viewset I get the correct representation of data for example:

```
data = {
  id: 1,
  issue_name: 'This is a problem',
  status: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'todo'
  }
}
```

The **problem** comes in when I need to **update the status**. For example if I want to select another status for this issue, for example:

```
status_new = {
   id: 4,
   name: 'done'
}
```

I send the following PATCH back to the server, this is the output:

```
data = {
  id: 1,
  issue_name: 'This is a problem',
  status: {
    id: 4,
    name: 'done'
  }

}
```

However, the status does not get updated. Infact, it is not even a part of the validated_data dictionary. I have read that nested relations are read-only. Could someone please tell me what I need to do this in a simple way?

Would really be obliged.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12):

As stated in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations), you will need to write your own `create()` and `update()` methods in your serializer to support writable nested data.

You will also need to explicitly add the status field instead of using the `depth` argument otherwise I believe it won't be automatically added to `validated_data`.

EDIT: Maybe I was a bit short on the details: what you want to do is override update in ModelIssueSerializer. This will basically intercept the PATCH/PUT requests on the serializer level. Then get the new status and assign it to the instance like this:

```
class StatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Status

class ModelIssueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = StatusSerializer()
    # ...
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        status = validated_data.pop('status')
        instance.status_id = status.id
        # ... plus any other fields you may want to update
        return instance
```

The reason I mentioned in the comment that you might need to add a `StatusSerializer` field is for getting status into `validated_data`. If I remember correctly, if you only use `depth` then nested objects might not get serialized inside the `update()` / `create()` methods (although I might be mistaken on that). In any case, adding the `StatusSerializer` field is just the explicit form of using `depth=1`

Comment: If I dont use depth, then how would I get the complete structure like:

status: {
    id: 4,
    name: 'done'
  }.

Can you give me or point me towards an example or a resource that does the update that you talking about?

Comment: Just define a ModelSerializer for Status and include it as a field in your other serializer, e.g. `status = StatusSerializer()`. As for examples for `update()`, there are a few in DRF's documentation (see the link in my answer)

Comment: I did try that, but defining a serializer for the status fields, causes the status record to be updated itself, which is not what I want.. Let me give an example:

`class ModeIIssue(models):
          name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
          status = ForeignKey(ModelStatus)
`

I want to update the reference of the status field and not the status record itself.

Comment: See my updated answer. Just a small piece of DRF advice: try to avoid writable ModelSerializers in cases like this. Writable ModelSerializers are useful when there is a simple, direct relationship between a model and an API endpoint like, for example, a concrete model with no modifiable relationships. The same is even more true for nested writable fields: the only case where it makes sense is fully contained models. In your case it's probably a better idea to route the PATCH/PUT verb on the issue's detail URL to a custom view that does the job. Much simpler and doesn't even break RESTfulness.

Comment: How can i update the values of instance in custom update() for many-to-many relationship. I am using an intermediate model for a many-to-many relationship, so instance.relationship.add() method is not allowed to use.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

Comment: @gbs I tried This way but I am not getting `status` object after serialization.

Comment: @gbs it seems that the 'id' field for status defaults to ReadOnlyField and thus doesn't get passed through to the `validated_data`.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use custom field for such cases.

```py
class StatusField(serializers.Field):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return StatusSerializer(value).data

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            return Status.objects.filter(id=data['id']).first()
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            pass
```

And then in main serializer:

```py
class IssueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = StatusField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyIssueModel
        fields = (
            'issue_name',
            'status',
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that your models mimic your serializer's data. Also, I would assume that you have a one to many relation with the status(es) but you don't need to create them via the issue serializer, you have a different endpoint for that. In such a case, you might get away with a [SlugRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield).

```python
from rest_framework import serializers


class StatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyStatusModel
        fields = (
            'id',
            'status',
        )


class IssueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='status', queryset=MyStatusModel.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = MyIssueModel
        fields = (
            'issue_name',
            'status',
        )
```

Another valid solution would be to leave here the foreign key value and deal with the display name on the front-end, via a ui-select or select2 component - the RESTfull approach: you are handling Issue objects which have references to Status objects. In an Angular front-end app, you would query all the statuses from the back-end on a specific route and then you will display the proper descriptive name based on the foreign key value form Issue.

Let me know how is this working out for you.

Comment: The idea behind is that I have an issue entry, which has a status. The status can be new, in progress, resolved etc. From the front end I can select another status, like resolved and then hit save. What I want is to when I hit save the issue should get updated via ajax. This flow runs fine for other fields of the issue model, but does not update the status field. I would add the **update** code, but the field **status** does not show up in the validated_data dictionary.

Comment: The list of statuses is "fixed" or configurable in the application in a different place ? You only need to refer the status here in the issue, right ?

Comment: Yes, the status is configurable at another place in the application and I need to refer to and change the status of the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Django is a little bit annoying that it ignores relationship fields if `depth = 1`

One explicit way to deal with this is to define 2 serializers, and define which to use in your Viewset

views:

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.MyModel.objects.order_by("pk")
    serializer_class = serializers.ExpandedSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == ["list", "retrieve"]:
            return serializers.MyExpandedSerializer
        if self.action in ["create", "update", "partial_update"]:
            return serializers.MyCreateSerializer
        return super(LenderOfferingViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Overload the create method with a different response serializer."""
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        response_serializer = serializers.MyExpandedSerializer(serializer.instance)
        return Response(response_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Overload method for PUT/PATCH to correctly set values and set response serializer."""
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
            # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
            # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
            instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

        response_serializer = serializers.MyExpandedSerializer(serializer.instance)
        return Response(response_serializer.data)
```

And then serializers:

```
class MyCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyObject
        fields = ["issue_name", "status"]
        depth = 0  # no expansion else create/update fail on missing fields (serializer ignores related fields)


class MyExpandedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """This serializer expands related fields explicitly with SerializerMethodFields."""
    class Meta:
        model = models.My
        fields = ["id", "issue_name", "status"]
        depth = 1
```

Then, when you

```
POST /my_endpoint/
{
  issue_name: 'This is a problem',
  status: 3
}
```

You will get the response (on i.e. /my_endpoint/1)

```
{
  id: 1,
  issue_name: 'This is a problem',
  status: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'todo'
  }
}
```