# Django Rest Framework - Updating a model using 'depth'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm having a problem updating a relation in a model using `ModelSerializer` and `depth`.

I've spent my whole day at this, I don't understand why this is happening.
This is my set-up (Ignore other relation fields):

**models.py**

```
class Condition(models.Model):
    """
    A model representing an electronic component's condition: New, used, pulled, etc...
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    """
    A model representing an electronic component
    """

    COMPONENT_TECH_CHOICES = (
        ('None', 'None'),
        ('TH', 'TH'),
        ('SMT', 'SMT'),
    )

    part_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    component_tech = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                  choices=COMPONENT_TECH_CHOICES,
                                  default=COMPONENT_TECH_CHOICES[0][0])
    rohs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # Should be 3-5 digits
    date_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, blank=True, null=True, related_name='items')
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package, blank=True, null=True, related_name='items')
    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, blank=True, null=True, related_name='items')
    condition = models.ForeignKey(Condition, blank=True, null=True, related_name='items')
    classification = models.ForeignKey(Classification, blank=True, null=True, related_name='items')

    owner = models.ForeignKey('authentication.Account', related_name='items')

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.part_number
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ConditionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Condition

class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        depth = 1
```

This is the request's payload:

```
case: {id: 1, name: "Tube", quantity: 100, created_at: "2016-02-13T12:32:27.588000Z",…}
classification: {id: 1, name: "Resistor", created_at: "2016-02-08T19:31:47.934000Z",…}
component_tech: "None"
condition: {id: 1, name: "New", created_at: "2016-02-13T14:00:02.788000Z",…}
created_at: "2015-12-17T17:33:46.562000Z"
date_code: "111"
description: "This is the description of the item"
id: 1
manufacturer: {id: 1, name: "Motorola", alias: "On-Semi", created_at: "2015-12-25T16:29:00Z",…}
owner: {id: 5, password: "pbkdf2_sha256$24000$IUUvIFU6Wjcx$Rayn8i9/QEyA+FyUQWaBOGvJHiz4K/hjYjeaOruDjvA=",…}
package: {id: 1, name: "DIP-14", created_at: "2016-02-13T14:43:36.246000Z",…}
part_number: "1N4148"
rohs: true
updated_at: "2016-02-19T21:24:58.256000Z"
```

condition has all the required fields (Even though some are hidden).

So, I really don't understand why is this happening.
DRF version is 3.3.1
However, I was able to figure that probably the relevant data has not reached `validated_data`.

At the end I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077256/django-rest-framework-updating-a-foreign-key) thread, but all I got from condition in `validated_data` in `update` was:

```
OrderedDict([(u'name', u'Used')])
```

Can anyone please point out what am I doing wrong, and why can't I update the relation in my Item/Condition?

**UPDATE:**

So, as I was investigating the `validated_data` issue in the `update` method in my serializer, I've stumbled upon the point-of-failure.

The `initial_data` the serializer gets is the request's payload (which is the good data)

However, after `serializer.is_valid()`, all the nested data disappears. I'm left with no related data. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: You need to write your own update method for nested serialization. Use ````validated_data.pop('condition ')```` to get the condition values and insert or fetch the ID and assign it to the ````condition_id````

Comment: Please read the last part of my post: I've tried to create my own ``update`` method, but all I got with ``validated_data.pop('condition')`` was ``OrderedDict([(u'name', u'Used')])``, and so I could not really updated the condition since I did not have its ID. Do you know why I got this partial OrederedDict?

Comment: Please post the updated serializer.

Comment: I did not change anything in any serializer. I merely investigated ModelSerializer.

Comment: you need to get the values of condition from validated_data and then create an item in the database before assigning it to the instance for update.

Comment: Again, please read what I said: I cannot get those values, since they do not pass serializer.is_valid(). ``initial_data`` has all info, but ``validated_data`` has only flat fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104051/discussion-between-akram-parvez-and-amir-tugi).

Answer (score 1):

it is very late to answer this now, but I found a simple solution which is make the depth dynamic, 0 when create or update and 1 when get

just add this init method to your serializer

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProcessSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    request = self.context.get('request')
    if request and (request.method == 'POST' or request.method == 'PUT'):
        self.Meta.depth = 0
    else:
        self.Meta.depth = 1
```

thanks to the 2nd answer of this question
[depth = 1 doesn't work properly and it's saves Null in ManyToManyField and ForeignKey fields in Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202824/depth-1-doesnt-work-properly-and-its-saves-null-in-manytomanyfield-and-forei/32212189)

Answer (score 0):

Answer after discussion

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    condition = ConditionSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        depth = 1

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        condition_inst = Condition.objects.get(**validated_data.pop('condition'))
        instance.condition_id = condition_inst.id
        for item in validated_data:
            if Item._meta.get_field(item):
                setattr(instance, item, validated_data[item])

        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: Yes, that was okay, but I told you that I may get MultipleObjectsReturned error, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Yes, you need to have unique names or use a field with unique value.

Answer (score 0):

method 1:
try this if you want to get data in depth = 1.

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    condition = ConditionSerializer(read_only = True)
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

if you want to get depth > 1 than mention depth in ConditionSerializer.

Method 2 :

```
from rest_framework.permissions import SAFE_METHODS

class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ItemSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    request = self.context.get('request')
    if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
        self.Meta.depth = 1
    else:
        self.Meta.depth = 0
```

Method 3 :

write two serializers one with depth one without depth.

write your view like this.

```
class ItemView(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()

def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
        return serializerwithdepth
    else:
        return serializerwithoutdepth
```